# Set numericUpDown to 0 if box is null

Tags: vb.net, null, numericupdown

First off I am working in VB.NET. I have a numeric up down control and any time the user uses the keyboard and clears out the number that is in the box I want it to set the value to 0.

I have tried this:

```
   If nudIntervalMonths.Value = vbNull Then
        nudIntervalMonths.Value = 0
   End If
```

But even when there is nothing in the box it still does not trigger that if statement. Where am I going wrong here. This seems like such a simple thing but I can't figure out how to get it to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't have a null in a NumericUpDown, can you?!  If the control loses focus, it will default back to the .MinimumValue.
Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: I think if they clear the text via the KB the `.Value` stays the same, just not shown.  The whole point of the NUD is that it always has a value from Min to Max.  The ability to remove the text portion doesnt make that clear to the user though.

Comment: It is WinForms. And it is keeping the value the same. I want the user to be able to clear out the box and have it store it as 0.

Comment: Just don't, the user had a good reason to clear out the text box.  He want to start typing something else.  Intentionally defeating his attempt is just hostile.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
If nudIntervalMonths.Controls.Item(1).Text = "" Then
            nudIntervalMonths.Value = 0
        End If
```

This worked like a charm.